# Issue with firebase integration in Objective C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, libraries

I'm trying to integrate firebase for cloud messaging(FirebaseMessaging) in my objective c project, when I do **pod install** facing below issue. My project is also having custom libraries.

[image]

Below are my .podspec and pod files.

[image]

[image]

to resolve above issue, I have added "use_modular_headers!" in my pod file and did **pod install** successfully.

[image]

when I open the app and trying to compile but I'm surprised that I have facing issues from my existing custom libraries which are successfully build before firebase integration in the app.

Please check the below file for the reference.
[image]

can anyone help on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `use_frameworks!` or `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` to the Podfile.

Firebase 9 dropped support for CocoaPods library integrations. More details in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios).